# Integration: ActiveCampaign to Zapier to Google Chat

Tags: zapier, google-hangouts, google-chat, activecampaign

I can create an integration in zapier that will notify me via google chat when I have a new lead that completes a form on activecampaign.

However, it's just a simple notification on google chat from a zap bot.  I would like the info that is transcribed into google chat to be hyperlinked to the lead contact record in active campaign.

Is that doable?  If so, how?

If not, are there any other solutions to what I am trying to accomplish?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a syntax available for GChat, so try this:

```
<https://anywhereontheinternet.com/|link>
```

so that `link` will have a hyperlink to https://anywhereontheinternet.com

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/chat/reference/message-formats/basic)